# JDBC sink connector insert/upsert based on max timestamp?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm very new to Kafka connect

I am inserting records from multiple sources into one table.
In some cases, it may be possible for some records to reach before others. 
Since I cannot control which source will pull which record first, I want to add a check on the timestamp key of the record.

I have a key called "LastModified_timestamp" in my schema where I store the timestamp of the latest state of my record.

I want to add a check to my JDBC sink connector where I can upsert a record based on comparing the value of LastModified_timestamp

I want to ignore the records which have a older timestamp and only want to upsert/insert the latest one. I couldn't find any configuration to achieve this

Is there any way by which I can achieve this? 
Will writing a custom query help in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JDBC Sink connector does not support this kind of feature. You have two options to consider:

- Single Message Transform (SMT) - these apply logic to records as they pass through Kafka Connect. SMT are great for things like dropping columns, changing datatypes, etc. *BUT* not appropriate for more complex processing and logic, including logic which needs to span multiple records as yours does here
- Process the data in the source Kafka topic first, to apply the necessary logic. You can do this with Kafka Streams, KSQL, and several other stream processing frameworks (e.g. Spark, Flink, etc). You'd need some kind of stateful logic that could work out if a record was older than already processed.

Can you describe more about your upstream source for the data? It might be there's a better way to orchestrate the data coming through to enforce the ordering.

A final idea would be to land *all* records to your target DB and then use logic in your database query consuming it to select the most recent (based on `LastModified_timestamp`) record for a given key.

*Disclaimer: I work for Confluent, the company behind the open-source KSQL project.*

Comment: this would make a great feature, if JDBC Sink can sink records just like the source can read based on id and timestamp